# Ignore blank rows not working while sorting in ASP.NET gridview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, aspxgridview

I have an ASP.NET gridview with 5 textboxes in every row. Page size of gridview is 20 records on each page. I have enabled sorting on every column. When the gridview is getting populated, then we are getting 28 filled records and 12 empty records.

When I hit sorting in asc mode on any column, it shows the blank rows earlier than the records with data. I want to ignore those blank records while sorting.

I tried using a custom `onsorting` method on gridview but it's not working.

Comment: can you show us?

Comment: You can try using a `CASE WHEN` clause in your ORDER BY statement to assign a different value to the blank rows depending on the sort order1. Alternatively, you can try setting the `AllowUserToAddRows` property of your DataGridView control to `False` to remove the empty rows

Comment: Can you please provide some example?